# How to hide only and show with out using any show function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using an ajax call.Is the results are not null then I need to show a div otherwise I need to hide that div.For that I used following code

```
      if(results == null)
        $('#divId').hide();
```

Here if the results are null then the div  going to be hide.It is working fine.But when I need to show the div in a different function again I need to use

```
       $('#divId').show();
```

So what I want is I need to hide only `results are null.`But I need to show the div in all remaining cases.Is there any elegant way to do that.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What's wrong with using an `else`?

Comment: nothing wrong but is there any better way

Comment: There are other ways. I wouldn't say they're _better..._

Comment: I just don't get it. Obviously, the OP knows how to use `else`. And he mentioned some 'different function' which has little connection with another parts of the question.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, if you mean that you don't want to repeat the code $("#divId").show() then you could use a mediator pattern. Have events like "dataAvalable" and "dataError" and have specific functions listen to those events when it happens. This could save you from repeating code, www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book You can stack events that are part of a process: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440809/good-pattern-to-use-for-multiple-xmlhttprequests-used-by-different-processes

Comment: @Downvoter who gave downvote for this.may i know the reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elegant? How about this:

```
$('#divId').toggle(results != null);
```

(In case it's not obvious, passing a boolean value to the [`.toggle()` method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-showOrHide) tells it whether to show or hide the element(s) in question.)

Comment: I suppose `$('#divId').toggle(results)` would be sufficient here.

Comment: +1 Indeed, it's the most elegant way if the only action that alternates on `results != null` is show/hide. )

Comment: @Koolinc - I don't think so, because `.toggle()` [can also accept an object](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-options) to tell it to do other things. For this purpose it needs an actual boolean, not just a truthy or falsey value.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$('#divId').css('display',(results == null)?'none':'block'); //You can use inline/block
```

But I suggest you to do check like this only

```
if(results == null){
   $('#divId').hide();
}else{
   $('#divId').show();
}
```

Comment: Did you test this? (Hint: you can't a sign a string equal to another string.)

Comment: Yes, it should be `.css('display', ...)` But even that is wrong; what if we need to restore the visibility of non-block element?

Answer (score 0):

Do not go for Micro-Optimization .Use

```
   if(results == null){
       $('#divId').hide();
   }else{
       $('#divId').show();
   }
```

And much simple way is Data truthify

```
 if(results){
       $('#divId').show();     
       }else{
          $('#divId').hide();
       }
```

Comment: i am not asking for optimisations.I am curious to know